# What route should a decorator of another route do

Tags: rest, decorator

Supposing I have a RESTful API where I post to `/doSomething` to start a task running. This task starts up an instance of a class that does something.

If I want to be able to add arbitrary functionality to that task, but keep the original class doing most of what it already did. The general wisdom is to use the decorator pattern on the class to add my desired functionality.

My stumbling block is that I can't think of an eloquent way to add this to the RESTful API. Options I have considered are:

- POST to `/doSomething/andALittleMore`. This gets confusing though because I could have multiple chained decorators and it might cause problems.
- POST to `/compose` and set up a bunch of different post parameters for both the original task and the decorator. This would be cumbersome with multiple decorators as well.
- POST to `/compose` and pass a set of options for the task and the decorator as JSON. This would add some order to which parameters are for which functionality, but the JSON would be a big mess.
- Have a route that accepts a composition command. Even more cumbersome because now I have to worry about what language this will work with, potentially tokenizing and parsing that command, etc.
- POST to `/doALittleMore` and pretend like `/doSomething` isn't part of the route. This takes away the descriptiveness of the URI.

I can't think of a way to accomplish what I'm looking to do that doesn't feel like it's taking the spirit of RESTfulness out of the API. But both REST and the decorator pattern have been around for a long time. How are these two designs generally combined?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest managing the decorators as their own endpoint, and treating them like a collection on the task.

```
GET /tasks/15/decorators - return all decorators on task 15
{
    "numDecorators": 15,
    "decorators": {
        {
            "self": "/decorators/3",
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}
POST /tasks/15/decorators - add a decorator on task 15
PUT /tasks/15/decorators - modify order, add, delete 

GET /decorators - return all decorators
POST /decorators - create a new decorator
```

etc ...

Another reasonable option would be to pull out the relationship into its own resource:

```
GET /tasks/15
GET /decorators/7
GET /task-decorators
```